# How to deal with compound command lines with RunProcess?

Tags: windows, command-line

Given `Windows` `DOS` command input:

```
tasklist|find /i "explorer.exe"
```

How to pass it to  `RunProcess` or similar function and get the output?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`RunProcess` does not run shell commands (things you might type into your terminal). It runs processes, as the name suggests.

If you want to run shell commands, then you have these options:

- [`Run`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Run.html) (it does not give you the output)
- `Import["!yourcommand", "String"]` or similar (to get the output)
- Run your shell with `RunProcess`/`StartProcess` and pass the commands to it on its standard input. [`StartProcess`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/StartProcess.html) has an example like this.
- For this specific task, run `cmd.exe` with [the `/c` flag](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/cmd) and tell it what to execute. [`RunProcess`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/RunProcess.html) has an example like this.

Comment: Thanks! but why `RunProcess[{"cmd", "/c", " tasklist | find /i \"explorer.exe\""}]` does not work?

Comment: `Import["! tasklist | find /i \"explorer.exe\"", "String"]` works! ;)

Comment: @Jerry I don't know how to get the quoting right. I do not use Windows.

Comment: It's already solved using `Import`, thanks for help!